# Android Webview - Webpage should fit the device screen

Tags: android, webview, scaling, android-webview

I have tried the following to fit the webpage based on the device screen size.

```
mWebview.setInitialScale(30);
```

and then set the metadata viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=medium-dpi"/>
```

But nothing works, webpage is not fixed to the device screen size.

Can anyone tell me how to get this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You have to calculate the scale that you need to use manually, rather than setting to 30.

```
private int getScale(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth(); 
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(PIC_WIDTH);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
}
```

Then use

```
WebView web = new WebView(this);
web.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
web.setInitialScale(getScale());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, u r right, it works. but I have different issue. I am not loading an image, loading the webpage in the webview, So how to find out the webpage width (PIC_WIDTH).

Comment: Ah, I missed that constant in there.  Sorry about that.  I am not sure how you can get the width of the actual webpage.

Comment: PIC_WIDTH was a constant that I knew beforehand, since I was just displaying a single image from the assets folder. As I said above, I don't know how you can get the width of the actual webpage.

Comment: but how about height? Do Android tablets have same ratio?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620732/html-data-not-display-correct-in-webview-gettinng-from-json-webservice-in-androi/21620839?noredirect=1#comment32670624_21620839 can you help me /

Comment: This solution definitely best solution. Before that I use javascript code for changing view metaport tag. This tag are used after page loading and this presents some lags, however I solved my delay problem.

Comment: what would be the expected value of PIC_WIDTH

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade i use PIC_WIDTH  = 360

Comment: @danh32 tell the value of PIC_WIDTH ... as 360 is not fine for me.

Comment: @danh32 Can the scale density (hdpi, mdpi) has impact on the calculation for scale?

Answer (score 327):

You can use this

```
    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

this fixes size based on screen size.

Comment: This feet the screen but does not allow you to make zoom in/out anymore. Could this issue bee improved?, I know it is possible on IOS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620732/html-data-not-display-correct-in-webview-gettinng-from-json-webservice-in-androi/21620839?noredirect=1#comment32670624_21620839  can you help me ?

Comment: this settings work for me but only for the width, in same cases now it is cuting off the height

Comment: This is the best solution to achieve this I've found so far.

Comment: The fact that the solution is built in really wins me over.

Comment: To add zoom, add the following: webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

Comment: @albanx what you did for height? any solution?

Answer (score 45):

These settings worked for me:

```
wv.setInitialScale(1);
wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

*setInitialScale(1)* was missing in my attempts.

Although documentation says that *0* will zoom all the way out if *setUseWideViewPort* is set to *true* but *0* did not work for me and I had to set *1*.

Comment: I wasnt setting the intial scale, and it worked for me for years. ( i was just setting overview mode, and viewport). But a new device Ive just come across seemed to start zoomed in until the page refreshed. Setting intial scale fixed this for me.

Comment: Didnt work for me as these settings were already used in my code, then it means there is issue with webpage content. Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

Friends,

I found a lot of import and great informations from you. But, the only way works for me was this way:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.noticiasWebView);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.resource.com.br/");
```

I am working on Android 2.1 because of the kind of devices from the company. But I fixed my problem using the part of informations from each one.

Thanks you!

Comment: Then zooming doesn't work anymore. I'm the only one with this problem?

Comment: @testing did you get any solution of it ?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi: No, I didn't. Because it was a test project for me I didn't further investigate into this. Let me know if you find something!

Comment: @AnshulTyagi: For web pages [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6182669/426227) is working for me. For images I have to use something different ...

Comment: Please change it to the latest code for Kotlin: `val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
 
var width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
var height = displayMetrics.heightPixels`

Comment: getRealMetrics is also deprecated in OS level 31. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display

Answer (score 25):

Try with this HTML5 tips

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying.html

And with this  if your Android Version is 2.1 or greater

```
  WebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Comment: unfortunately they deprecated this and this solution was failing for me on Galaxy S5

Answer (score 15):

All you need to do is simply

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: It worked for me without setLayoutAlgorithm as well

Answer (score 14):

These work for me and fit the WebView to screen width:

```
// get from xml, with all size set "fill_parent"  
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_in_layout);  
// fit the width of screen
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN); 
// remove a weird white line on the right size
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Thanks above advises and [White line in eclipse Web view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564023/white-line-in-eclipse-web-view)

Comment: It seems SINGLE_COLUMN is deprecated now http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html

Answer (score 13):

I have same problem when I use this code

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
}
```

so may be you should **remove** it in your code
And remember to add 3 modes below for your webview

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

this fixes size based on screen size

Comment: @shahzainali you can zoom your webview?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi No it doesn't zoom.

Answer (score 8):

I had video in html string, and width of web view was larger that screen width and this is working for me.

Add these lines to HTML string.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
```

Result after adding above code to HTML string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>


</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
browser.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(40);
```

This works great for me since the text size has been set to really small by .setLoadWithOverViewMode and .setUseWideViewPort.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use HTML in your webView in this case. I solved this using following code

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
                "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><img src= "
                        + \"http://www.koenvangorp.be/photos/2005_09_16-moon_2000.jpg\"
                        + " alt=\"pageNo\" width=\"100%\"></body></html>",
                "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: i guess is better to use px ot vh instead of %. % in iframes have some bugs on orientation changes

Answer (score 5):

Making Changes to the answer by danh32 since the  display.getWidth(); is now deprecated.

```
private int getScale(){
    Point p = new Point();
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    display.getSize(p);
    int width = p.x; 
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(PIC_WIDTH);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
}
```

Then use

```
WebView web = new WebView(this);
web.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
web.setInitialScale(getScale());
```

Comment: I calculated that the scale should be < 1 or 100% so I compared my width with the PIC_WIDTH to get the ratio. More than that I also deducted some padding.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like an XML problem. Open the XML document containing your Web-View. Delete the padding code at the top.

Then in the layout , add

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

In the Web-View, add

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

This makes the Web-View fit the device screen.

Comment: that's what saves my time.

Comment: fill_parent is outdated, use match_parent.

Answer (score 3):

```
int PIC_WIDTH= webView.getRight()-webView.getLeft();
```

Comment: getRight and getLeft always returns 0 for me

Answer (score 3):

```
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

will work, but remember to remove something like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no"/>
```

if existed in the html file or change user-scalable=yes, otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 3):

For any developer landed here and facing a problem dealing with Webview initial zoom/scale(especially in custom webpages).

```
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false); //make sure this method is false so setInitialScale() can work correctly
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(110);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help in adjusting the emulator according to the webpage:

```
WebView wb;
//CALL THIS METHOD
wb.setInitialScale(50);
```

You can set the intial scale in percentage as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

The getWidth method of the Display object is deprecated. Override onSizeChanged to get the size of the WebView when it becomes available.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(context) {

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int ow, int oh) {

        // if width is zero, this method will be called again
        if (w != 0) {

            Double scale = Double.valueOf(w) / Double.valueOf(WEB_PAGE_WIDTH);

            scale *= 100d;

            setInitialScale(scale.intValue());
        }

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, ow, oh);
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you get `WEB_PAGE_WIDTH`?

Comment: If you are trying to scale some fixed width content to fit the screen, then you should know in advance how wide your content is. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK this should work for images. But for webpages (which can be responsive) it can be any width > 320px for example.

Answer (score 1):

In theory the combination of:

```
settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
```

with

```
settings.setUseWideViewPort(false)
```

fixes the problem, wrapping the content and fitting to the screen. But the *[NARROW_COLUMNS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html)* has been deprecated. I advice you to read this thread below that explores the issue in detail: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62378

Answer (score 1):

here's an updated version, not using deprecated methods, based upon @danh32's answer:

```
protected int getScale(Double contentWidth) {
    if(this.getActivity() != null) {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        Double val = displaymetrics.widthPixels / contentWidth * 100d;
        return val.intValue();
    } else {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

to be used alike:

```
int initialScale = this.getScale(420d);
this.mWebView.setInitialScale(initialScale);
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this is a Kotlin implementation of @danh32's solution:

```
private fun getWebviewScale (contentWidth : Int) : Int {
    val dm = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(dm)
    val pixWidth = dm.widthPixels;
    return (pixWidth.toFloat()/contentWidth.toFloat() * 100F)
             .toInt()
}
```

In my case, width was determined by three images to be 300 pix so:

```
webview.setInitialScale(getWebviewScale(300))
```

It took me hours to find this post.  Thanks!

Answer (score -5):

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.setInitialScale((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._50sdp)); // getActivity(). if you are at Fragment
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,here comes html content,"text/html","UTF-8", null);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Comment: Please do not post two answers with the same content just because of down votes.

Comment: And please format you code spending a bit of effort! Why did you indent it to the right so much? Too much time to delete some white space?