# How to fit a webpage on android screen(webview)?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Webview - Webpage should fit the device screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen)

I want to render a webpage in android's webview. Currently, I can display a webpage but how to make it fit within the screen?
I referred to:
[Android Webview - Webpage should fit the device screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen)
but didn't find a solution there.

Thanks!!

Comment: Its not a duplicate, because the guy already said he checked that question and didn't find a solution...

Comment: It would have helped if the OP had said _why_ @Richard. This question may not be a duplicate but there's absolutely no information to enable anyone to answer it. It should remain closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but if I'm guessing you mean the `webview` is not expanding to fit the whole screen? Please post your code to support your question.

To make the `webview` expand to the whole screen, add the `webview` in your activity layout xml and make sure you set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` to fill_parent. Here's a simple example:

```
  <LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <WebView  
          android:id="@+id/webview"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Ryan

Comment: I already have a webview with "fill_parent", what I want is the webpage I am loading in a webview should fit exactly in that webview without scrollbars. And later the user should be able to zoom in and zoom out to view the content of webpage.

Comment: Take a look at this answer by Brian, might be what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808532/how-to-set-the-initial-zoom-width-for-a-webview

Answer (score 29):

The only way that works for me was this way:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.noticiasWebView);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.resource.com.br/");
```

I am working on Android 2.1 because of the kind of devices from the company. But I fixed my problem using the part of informations from each one.

Comment: cannot believe that it is not working without setInitialScale   .... unbelievable

Comment: zooming doesn't work anymore ...

Comment: @testing, did you find the solution. If you did, please, post it.

Comment: @DevetiPutnik: For web pages [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6182669/426227) is working for me. For images I have to use something different ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me on the marshmallow even, but zooming isn't working anymore.

Comment: can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098464/loading-gif-in-webview-not-adjusting-to-webview

Answer (score 8):

My solution was different.
I made a webpage big enough so it would then get zoomed out. And in the webview settings i put the following:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
//webview.setInitialScale(100); No need for this one
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
settings.setLightTouchEnabled(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Be sure to import the following: `import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity;`

Comment: Forgot to say that you must delete the **viewport metatag** in your HTML for this to work.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I have just tested your answer with my web view implementation, it simply works. Why do not work with viewport metatag, viewport is created for mobile device compatibility? Many Thanks.