# White line in eclipse Web view

Tags: jquery, android, eclipse, mobile

I am making a android app  using jquery  mobile and web view with eclipse.

When i test it in the emulator or export it to my galaxy s2 i get a white line on the right and the whole app can be moved around.

When i put the code in phonegap it works ok but i want to build it in eclipse so why do i get the white stuff on the right?  Here is a link to the emulator:

http://www.lucyseven.com/screen.jpg

Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me:

```
WebView webVw = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourwebview);
webVw.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML, and set it to fill_parent for width.

Comment: This is what i have in my xml:

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>