# WebView doesn't resize on some HTML pages

Tags: android, html, webview, resize, size

So, [this is the HTML](http://app.avlabs.it/odcec/page-crediti.php?login=demo&password=demo) I want to load in my `WebView` and it doesn't resize. I'm using the same Activity to load these HTMLs (same width): [this](http://app.avlabs.it/odcec/page-convenzioni.php) and [this](http://app.avlabs.it/odcec/page-contatti.php)

I have used many things to resize and I get no resized with none:

- [`webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
      webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjYIM.png) (picture)

Tried as well on `WebClient.onPageFinished`

I'm getting my page refreshed (or the View) as well every 1 - 3 seconds automatically, getting a lot of messages from Logcat like:

```
onSizeChanged - w:480 h:0

onSizeChanged - w:480 h:491

onSizeChanged - w:480 h:1887
```

and many more...

- [`WebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUxzE.png) (picture)

  2. Tried `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`
  3. Tried [this(on OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen)

The weird thing is that other pages work corretly.

My code is this:

```
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webView.loadUrl(URL);

    WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        } 
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    webView.setWebViewClient(client);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

if this happens, means that the HTML has tags like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable=no">`

and **`user-scalable=no`** doesn't allow to scale the HTML.