# Webview font size in android

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview in my android application. Problem with textsize. In android 4.4, the text size id very small. But in android 5.0 or later it is very big in size. How to overcome this?

Comment: Have you tried to add style to your html content?

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to add styles? webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(20); tried this one but not working?

Comment: Just google "set style to html webview android" there are many ways you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the snippet

```
     WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
     webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html.html");
```

For setting initial zoom [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen)