# how to display all size pages in one webview?

Tags: android, webview

I'm devloping an apk to display some web pages by using webview.
The web pages have two size: 
640*530

```
<meta name="page-view-size" content="640*530" />
```

[it's diaplayed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDLpN.jpg)

1280*720

```
<meta name="page-view-size" content="1280*720" />
```

[it's now displayed full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxI39.jpg)

How can i display all size pages in fullscreen with one webview?

The device is version is Android 4.4.2

I've tried these methods:

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

neither one is work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: how to scale the 640*530 page to full screen?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for your web page header:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" width="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: thanks a lot.but the web page is online, and can not be modfied.

Comment: oh. so you can read for solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, all the methods i listed above were from the same solution you mentioned.

Comment: I think is really deficult if you are not  website owner because screen fit depend on website header... also unless you get lucky in sometimes load website