# Load url with minimum zooming width - android

Tags: android

I have a web view and when it is loading URL, it is already zoomed in with some percentage. i.e. user has to scroll horizontally to see the entire content. I want to load the web page with minimum zooming size. i.e. user cannot be zoom out anymore at the time of loading. I tried below, but it is showing the entire page in the web view at once. ultimately I want to fit the web page horizontally.

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen

Answer (score 0):

Just use setMinimumFontSize and setUseWideViewPort(true) like below. (Y)

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wv.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(35);
```