# How to get the full height of in android WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I have a `RelativeLayout` with `WebView`. I am loading some generated html text into that `WebView`. After loading the data `WebView` height exceeding the screen. Now I need the height of the entire `WebView`. Till now I tried `WebView#getHeight()`, `WebView#getBottom()` but I'm getting the height of visible content.

How to get the total height of `WebView`.?
[image: screen height]

Comment: you have to use javascript for that.

Comment: Can you tell me how ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally I got the answer for my question. Here is the answer.

After loading `WebView` we will get call in `WebViewClient#onPageFinished` there we need to call javascript to get the height of full content of `WebView`

`WebViewClient` class

```
/**
 * Custom web client to perform operations on WebView
 */
class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:AndroidFunction.resize(document.body.scrollHeight)");
        }
    }
}
```

After that we will get callback with height in `WebInterface` class which is Registered as `JavascriptInterface`

```
/**
 * WebView interface to communicate with Javascript
 */
public class WebAppInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void resize(final float height) {
        float webViewHeight = (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        //webViewHeight is the actual height of the WebView in pixels as per device screen density
    }
}
```

Comment: resizing is crucial if actual height in screen pixels is needed. thanks a lot.

Comment: hey, what is readWebView? Ah- an instance of WebAppInterface?

Comment: No it's webView instance. Edited answer. Thanks man. I forgot that it's my answer. ;)

Comment: how to use this class WebAppInterface

Comment: go through this link https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript

Comment: Since `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` only gets called when the page had finished loading, this solution falls short when the size of the content changes post loading (e.g. Javascript content rendered after page finished loading, user interactions with expandable and collapsible sections)

Comment: In this case we can have one more javascript call from web page when content is expanded/collapsed.

Comment: @trod I'm also facing similar problem. Do have any clue?

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your `WebView` within a `ScrollView` and `webView.getHeight()` will return the height of the actual WebView content. Make sure your `WebView`'s height attribute is set to `wrap_content`.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </WebView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried this case also, but if we load 10 high quality images it is giving out off  memory error. And one more thing keeping WebView in ScrollView is not recommended.

Comment: @shobhan You're probably getting OOM because the images are much higher res than what the device can handle, consider if a high res image is 50mb, you load 10 = 250mb, and then on top of that you have the app, the os, etc. running on oftentimes devices with less than a gig of ram, you're going to kill your app quickly.

Comment: I think you tried to explain part of my above comment. (OOM out off memory error) :P Thanks.

Comment: If you are using scroll view among with nested scroll view try to set 
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" inside scroll view

Comment: NEVER wrap webViews inside scrollviews. It will make the WebView expand to max size and the webView will believe all of it's content is shown. WebView should handle content visibility, not ScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView{
    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    int ContentHeight = 0;
    public int getContentHeight(){
        if(ContentHeight==0)
            ContentHeight = computeVerticalScrollRange();
        return ContentHeight;
    }
}
```

Webview has protected method `computeVerticalScrollRange()`. you can access this method by creating custom one.

```
((CustomWebView) webView).getContentHeight())
```

Comment: the word `compute` tends to indicate that some work is being done, possibly heavy.

Comment: I get a ```ClassCastException``` with this solution. Any work arounds?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 2):

kotlin:
myWebView.contentHeight

Comment: In my case I aloso need multiply myWebView.contentHeigth to Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density to get real height.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:-

I think you have to remove padding properties from your layout.xml file

(i.e) Remove the following content from your XML file and try it.

```
android:paddingBottom    
android:paddingLeft    
android:paddingRight    
android:paddingTop
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

In your Java class add the getWindow()

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private int getScale(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth(); 
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(PIC_WIDTH);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
}
```

check this   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen)! for more information