# webview height returns 0

Tags: android, webview

when I try to below code `webview.heigth` returns 0. I don't understand whats wrong with the code. I also tried the `measuredheight` instead of height but the result is still same.

```
 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(realtyDetail.descriptionHtml)) {
        webViewHtml.loadData(FormatUtil.formatSpecialCharsForWebView(realtyDetail.descriptionHtml), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8")
        ellWebView.visible()
        txtDescription.visible()
        webViewHtml.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        val vto = view!!.viewTreeObserver;
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                if (vto.isAlive) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    } else {
                        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                        vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)
                    }
                    if (!webViewHtmlSet && webViewHtml != null) {
                        val limit = DeviceUtil.convertDpToPixel(400f, context)

                        if (webViewHtml.height > limit) {
                            setWebView(limit)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

layout:

```
 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewHtml"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

html:(my webview height is `wrap_content` but only below html not working)

```
<font style="font-size:22px"><font style="background-color:#00ff00"><font style="color:#000000"><i>KOCAELİ KARAMÜRSEL AVCİ KOYDE KÖY CIVARI MEVKİNDE 723M2 MUSTEKİL PARSEL SATILIK TIR <br/></i></font></font></font><font style="font-size:22px"><font style="background-color:#00ff00"><font style="color:#000000"><i><br/></i></font></font></font><font style="font-size:22px"><font style="background-color:#00ff00"><font style="color:#000000"><i>PARKE YOLA CEPHE LI DÜMDÜZ &#37;30 KONUT IMARLI ARSA,DIR DÜMDÜZ CEVİZ BAHÇESİ ELEKTRİK HATTI ŞEBEKE SU HATTI YANINDAN GEÇMEKTEDİR KANALIZASYON TÜM ALT YAPILARI TAMAMLANMIŞ TIR TOPLU ULAŞIM VARDIR ARADIĞINIZ HER ŞEY YÜRÜ ME MESAFESINDE DİR CAMI KAHVANE BERBER NALBUR PETROL OFİSİ SAĞLIK OCAĞI İTFAİYE ILKÖĞRETİM <br/></i></font></font></font><font style="font-size:22px"><font style="background-color:#00ff00"><font style="color:#000000"><i><br/></i></font></font></font><font style="font-size:22px"><font style="background-color:#00ff00"><font style="color:#000000"><i>Not istek halinda yan KOMŞU  parselde SATILIK 1013m2<br/></i></font></font></font><font style="font-size:22px"><font style="background-color:#00ff00"><font style="color:#000000"><i><br/></i></font></font></font><font style="font-size:22px"><font style="background-color:#00ff00"><font style="color:#ff0000"><i>DAHA DETAYLI BILGI ALMAK İÇİN BIZI ARAYINIZ </i></font></font></font>
```

by the way this is working on simulator but on real device the html doesn't work and the height returns 0.

Comment: Probably content hasn't been loaded yet. Try using the `WebView` callback, something like `onPageFinished` or so.

Comment: This answer may help: > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394498/how-to-get-the-full-height-of-in-android-webview

Comment: @Onik I have tried inside onpagefimished callback but the result is still same

Comment: can you post how you are creating webview

Comment: @Jayanth i posted

Comment: What is the parent view of your webview (XML)? ScrollView or regular layout?

Comment: @TaslimOseni the parent of webview is ExpandableLinearLayout. but only the html which I write on question not working. all of the other html are working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach `viewTreeObserver` to the `WebView` on `onPageFinished()` callback on the `WebViewClient` like below. it gives the exact height of your webView.

```
  webView.webViewClient = Client()
    webView.loadData(Base64.encodeToString("<font style=\"font-size:22px\"><font style=\"background-color:#00ff00\"><font style=\"color:#000000\"><i>KOCAELİ KARAMÜRSEL AVCİ KOYDE KÖY CIVARI MEVKİNDE 723M2 MUSTEKİL PARSEL SATILIK TIR <br/></i></font></font></font><font style=\"font-size:22px\"><font style=\"background-color:#00ff00\"><font style=\"color:#000000\"><i><br/></i></font></font></font><font style=\"font-size:22px\"><font style=\"background-color:#00ff00\"><font style=\"color:#000000\"><i>PARKE YOLA CEPHE LI DÜMDÜZ &#37;30 KONUT IMARLI ARSA,DIR DÜMDÜZ CEVİZ BAHÇESİ ELEKTRİK HATTI ŞEBEKE SU HATTI YANINDAN GEÇMEKTEDİR KANALIZASYON TÜM ALT YAPILARI TAMAMLANMIŞ TIR TOPLU ULAŞIM VARDIR ARADIĞINIZ HER ŞEY YÜRÜ ME MESAFESINDE DİR CAMI KAHVANE BERBER NALBUR PETROL OFİSİ SAĞLIK OCAĞI İTFAİYE ILKÖĞRETİM <br/></i></font></font></font><font style=\"font-size:22px\"><font style=\"background-color:#00ff00\"><font style=\"color:#000000\"><i><br/></i></font></font></font><font style=\"font-size:22px\"><font style=\"background-color:#00ff00\"><font style=\"color:#000000\"><i>Not istek halinda yan KOMŞU  parselde SATILIK 1013m2<br/></i></font></font></font><font style=\"font-size:22px\"><font style=\"background-color:#00ff00\"><font style=\"color:#000000\"><i><br/></i></font></font></font><font style=\"font-size:22px\"><font style=\"background-color:#00ff00\"><font style=\"color:#ff0000\"><i>DAHA DETAYLI BILGI ALMAK İÇİN BIZI ARAYINIZ </i></font></font></font>".toByteArray(), Base64.NO_PADDING), "text/html", "base64")
```

....

```
private inner class Client: WebViewClient(){
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            webView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
                Log.d("xifi", "${webView.height}")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the output I got for your HTML
[image: Logcat]

This is emulator displaying webPage

[image: Emulator]

Comment: i don't know why but its only not workin on real device. did you set height to wrap_content. in emulator this is working for me as well.

Comment: can u please try it out on real device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209673/discussion-between-ali-gurelli-and-jayanth).

Comment: I really wonder why this worked. is there a problem with html that I shared?

Comment: do you have any idea why this solutions has been worked?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, maybe because of encoding issues. you can check more info here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)