# full height of webview website second page

Tags: java, android, html, css, xml

I have a webview with the following problem: on android and desktop it works perfectly on the first page, but when I click the button to go to the second page, the height of the page does not show entirely. Only in android, the scroll and buttons are not responding, desktop is fine. It's an android project downloaded from another github user...

[This is the first page working great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIwaf.jpg)

[This is the second page issue with scroll and buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59TDM.jpg)

This is the XML layout code file:

[xml code part one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQzWo.png)
[xml code part two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy84Y.png)

and here are the more important lines about the webview settings located in MainActivity.java file

[mainactivty.java webview settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60dkV.png)

**NOTE:** Normally the website is responsive and working perfectly, whatever android, ios, etc... device, its totally responsive and works fine into a web browser in mobile device, tested physically with real device ***(no android emulator)***

The issue is only with the second page...

Comment: This might answer your question:
[How to get the full height of in android WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394498/how-to-get-the-full-height-of-in-android-webview)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove the web view from the NestedScrollView and make it match_parent