# Webview the large photos in the content part do not fit on the screen Android Application

Tags: java, android, wordpress, webview

In the Android application, I show only the wordpress content part as a webview. However, the large photos in the content part do not fit on the screen and the screen becomes able to move left and right. How can I find a solution.

Comment: Does the [solution here help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen)?

Comment: it didn't work for me. I'm not pulling the whole page, I'm pulling the content with json